# pip install python-qpid-proton: how to fix errors on windows?

Tags: python, pip, amqp, qpid, qpid-proton

While running pip install python-qpid-proton I got the following errors:

1. *error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.*
   I fixed this by installing Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 and Visual Studio Professional 2022
2. *fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler generated file*
   This error appears apparently if the path is too long. Therefore I changed the path of the Temp folder to a shorter path. I have done this by creating a new folder under C:\Windows\TEMP and changed setting the following environmental variables:
   TEMP=C:\TEMP and TMP=C:\TEMP
3. After these two steps I get a different error. Has someone an idea how to solve this? Maybe there is also a different way to install python-qpid-proton on windows? I would appreciate that a lot...

The error comes after a lot of warnings in this form

```
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\src\core\buffer.c(279): warning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\src\core\buffer.c(280): warning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\src\core\buffer.c(273): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data
```

Then there are the errors:

```
cproton_wrap.c  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/object.h(242): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 
'pn_list_index'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/object.h(242): error C2059: syntax error: ';'         
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/object.h(242): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter
-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/object.h(280): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 
'pn_string_put'
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/object.h(280): error C2059: syntax error: ';'        
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/object.h(280): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter
-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(546): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '
pn_data_encode'
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(546): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(546): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-
list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(555): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '  
pn_data_encoded_size'
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(555): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(555): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-
list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(574): error C2061: syntax error: identifier '
pn_data_decode'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(574): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/codec.h(574): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-
list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/link.h(587): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'p
n_link_send'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/link.h(587): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/link.h(587): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-l
ist>'   
 C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/link.h(640): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'p
n_link_recv'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/link.h(640): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/link.h(640): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-l
ist>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(489): error C2061: syntax error: identifi  
er 'pn_transport_input'
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(489): error C2059: syntax error: ';'       
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(489): error C2059: syntax error: '<parame
ter-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(494): error C2061: syntax error: identifi  
er 'pn_transport_output'
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(494): error C2059: syntax error: ';'     
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(494): error C2059: syntax error: '<parame
ter-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(513): error C2061: syntax error: identifi
er 'pn_transport_capacity'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(513): error C2059: syntax error: ';'     
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(513): error C2059: syntax error: '<parame
ter-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(546): error C2061: syntax error: identifi
er 'pn_transport_push'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(546): error C2059: syntax error: ';'     
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(546): error C2059: syntax error: '<parame
ter-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(593): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'pn_transport_pending'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(593): error C2059: syntax error: ';'     
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(593): error C2059: syntax error: '<parame
ter-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(625): error C2061: syntax error: identifi
er 'pn_transport_peek'
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(625): error C2059: syntax error: ';'     
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/transport.h(625): error C2059: syntax error: '<parame
ter-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/message.h(752): error C2061: syntax error: identifier
 'pn_message_encode2'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/message.h(752): error C2059: syntax error: ';'       
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/message.h(752): error C2059: syntax error: '<paramete
r-list>'  
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/message.h(777): error C2061: syntax error: identifier
 'pn_message_send'  
      C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/message.h(777): error C2059: syntax error: ';'       
C:\Temp\pip-install-rv64pyj0\python-qpid-proton_043295171d11447ab93794ab575dd56d\include\proton/message.h(777): error C2059: syntax error: '<paramete
r-list>'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3131): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'wrap_pn_link_recv'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3131): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3131): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3142): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'wrap_pn_transport_peek'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3142): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3142): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3191): error C2061: syntax error: identifier 'wrap_pn_data_encode'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3191): error C2059: syntax error: ';'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3191): error C2059: syntax error: '<parameter-list>'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3760): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3760): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'result'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3760): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3784): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3784): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3784): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pn_link_send'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3784): warning C4013: 'pn_link_send' undefined; assuming extern returning int  
      cproton_wrap.c(3787): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3806): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3806): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'result'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3806): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3824): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3824): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3824): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier  
 'wrap_pn_link_recv'   
      cproton_wrap.c(3824): warning C4013: 'wrap_pn_link_recv' undefined; assuming extern returning int    
      cproton_wrap.c(3827): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier    
      cproton_wrap.c(3845): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier    
      cproton_wrap.c(3845): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'result'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3845): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3869): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3869): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3869): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier  'pn_transport_push'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3869): warning C4013: 'pn_transport_push' undefined; assuming extern returning int  
      cproton_wrap.c(3872): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3891): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3891): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'result'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3891): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3909): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3909): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(3909): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier  
 'wrap_pn_transport_peek'  
      cproton_wrap.c(3909): warning C4013: 'wrap_pn_transport_peek' undefined; assuming extern returning int  
      cproton_wrap.c(3912): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier   
      cproton_wrap.c(4005): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier   
      cproton_wrap.c(4005): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'result'   
      cproton_wrap.c(4005): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier    
      cproton_wrap.c(4029): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier    
      cproton_wrap.c(4029): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier    
      cproton_wrap.c(4029): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'pn_data_decode'    
      cproton_wrap.c(4029): warning C4013: 'pn_data_decode' undefined; assuming extern returning int  
      cproton_wrap.c(4032): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(4051): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(4051): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'result'  
      cproton_wrap.c(4051): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(4069): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(4069): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(4069): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'wrap_pn_data_encode'  
      cproton_wrap.c(4069): warning C4013: 'wrap_pn_data_encode' undefined; assuming extern returning int  
      cproton_wrap.c(4072): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(12214): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(12214): error C2146: syntax error: missing ';' before identifier 'result'  
      cproton_wrap.c(12214): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(12234): error C2065: 'result': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(12234): error C2065: 'ssize_t': undeclared identifier  
      cproton_wrap.c(12234): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Professional\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.32.31326\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with 
exit code 2`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the last error by using Python 3.9 instead of Python 3.10. Apparently python-qpid-proton 0.37.0 is only compatible with Python 3.9.

Comment: For anyone interested, I could actually install and use v0.37.0 on Python3.10 and Ubuntu 20.04.